# Google analytics for custom data not working as expected

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have added my gtag javascript code on the top of the pages, and then inside my `script.js` file I have written something like this:

```
    ga('send', {
        hitType: 'event',
        eventCategory: 'EditorPage',
        eventAction: 'login',
        eventLabel: 'User Logged In : ' + localUser.email + ' from orgId ' + localUser.orgId
    });
    ga('send', {
        hitType: 'event',
        eventCategory: localUser.orgId,
        eventAction: 'Track user by Organisation Id',
        eventLabel: 'Org Id'
    });
    ga('send', {
        hitType: 'event',
        eventCategory: localUser.email,
        eventAction: 'Track user by User Email',
        eventLabel: 'User Email'
    });
```

I am trying to register here, 1) who logged in, 2) the organization ID, 3) the user email ID.

Now when creating a dashboard the only option I get to plot a scatter plot or graph is this :

[image]

[image]

I am not able to plot a graph with only orgIds or User Email. 
For example : `Org Wise ID grouping in Pie Chart or Table`

How can I plot a pie chart for each event individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display org id ,try adding a filter to your widget with event action as "Track user by Organisation Id"  like below

[image: Filter by event action]